# Does FFmpeg lib support set time range at PLAY packet's "range" header field when get video from RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, onvif, live555

I want to get a video with start time and end time from RTSP server.
From Maxim-zapryanov's answer at [the discussion](https://github.com/onvif/specs/discussions/127#discussioncomment-955277), I know to do it, I need set time range at PLAY packet's "range" header field

> To play from a specific time you need to use the RTSP header field
> "range" for the PLAY command. See section 6.5.1 of
> https://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec.pdf and
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2326#section-12.29

I used Live555 lib to set the field to PLAY packet success. But I want set the field by FFmpeg lib instead of Live555 lib.

So, does FFmpeg lib support set time range at PLAY packet's "range" header field when get video from RTSP? If yes, how to do it?

If anyone know the answer, please tell me know. Thank you so much!